# How do I solve for the recurrence relation when P does not exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, recurrence-relations, matrix-decomposition

I'm using the method that my textbook uses. I first put the recurrence relation in the form of a matrix. After that I solve for the eigenvalues and eigenspaces to find P. Then they use P to find D and finally plug everything into $A^k = PD^kP^{-1}$ I did this for a problem before and got the correct answer, but not I'm stuck. I have an eigenvalue with algebraic multiplicity of 2 but an eigenspace of 1. So, P does not exist.

The problem is: $y_1$ = 1, $y_2$ = 6, $Y_n = 4Y_{n-1} - 4Y_{n-2}$ for $ n \ge 3$

$$A =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        4 & -4  \\
        1 & 0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

I find that the eigenvalue is $(\lambda - 2)^2$ = 0 so $\lambda$ = 2

Finally I solve for the eigenspace and get $E_2$ = span $
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2 \\
        1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$

Am I making a mistake?

Comment: Not only $P$ does not exist, neither does $D$. But you can make it similar to a upper triangular matrix $T$. It's not a diagonal matrix, but its still simple to finds its powers.

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Comment: There are basically two typical ways to go about this. One is to find the [Jordan Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) of $A$, the other is to triangularize $A$. Any complex matrix is triangularizable (in other words, similar to a triangular matrix, usually upper triangular is chosen). In [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587257/how-do-i-find-upper-triangular-form-of-a-given-3-by-3-matrix/587321#587321) answer I explain with a $3\times 3$ example how to triangularize a matrix.

Comment: But if this problem was presented to you, then most likely you were taught one of these methods and you should use it. If you weren't taught any of this, I suppose the best thing to do is to compute a few powers of $A$ directly and try to find a pattern. the solution is $A^n=\begin{bmatrix} 2^n(n+1) & -2^{n+1}n\\ 2^{n-1}n& -2^n(n-1)\end{bmatrix}$, for all $n\in \mathbb N$. You can always take a vector $v$ such that $\left\{\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}, v\right\}$is alinearly independent set. This will always make $P^{-1}AP$ upper triangular.

Comment: If no one answers your question, it would be nice if you gave an answer so this doesn't come up as unanswered.

Comment: I would give the answer, but I'm still not sure if I am correct. I took v= [0 1] and then while solving I got $$ A^n=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        2(4)^n-2(-4)^n & 2(-4)^n \\
        (-4)^n & 2(4)^n+2(-4)^n \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: You can easily check that what you got fails for $n=1$.You must have made a mistake in the calculations somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to linear algebra, we can proceed via generating functions. Let $Y(x):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_n x^n$ with $\{y_n\}$ the sequence defined in the question. Then we may write

\begin{align}
Y(x)
&=y_1x+y_2x^2+ \sum_{n=3}^\infty y_n x^n\\
&=x+6x^2+\sum_{n=3}^\infty (4y_{n-1}-4y_{n-2}) x^n\\
&=x+6x^2+4x\sum_{n=2}^\infty y_{n} x^n-4x^2\sum_{n=1}^\infty y_{n} x^n \\
&=x+6x+4x(Y(x)-1)-4x^2Y(x)
\end{align}
where in the second line we have used the recurrence relation. Solving for $Y(x)$ then gives $$Y(x)=\dfrac{x+2x^2}{1-4x+4x^2}=\dfrac{x(1-2x)+4x^2}{(1-2x)^2}=\dfrac{x}{1-2x}+\frac{4x^2}{(1-2x)^2}.$$

Since the coefficients of $Y(x)$ are the sequence $\{y_n\}$, all that remains is to expand both terms in a Taylor series and identify coefficients on both sides.

There's a few ways to do this; I'll do so by writing the generating function using derivatives as $Y(x)=x\left(1-2x\dfrac{d}{dx}\right)\dfrac{1}{1-2x}$. Since $\dfrac{1}{1-2x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n$ is a geometric series, we can differentiate term-by-term. A little algebra then gives $Y(x)=x+\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty 2^{n-1}(2n-1)x^n$. Hence $y_n=2^{n-1}(2n-1)$ for $n \geq 2$.