# Unitary Complex Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, diagonalization

Let $M$ be a complex matrix $$M:=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 & i & -i \\
        i & 0 & 1 \\
        -i & 1 & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$
**1)** Find a unitary complex matrix $Q$ such that $Q^HMQ$ is an upper-triangular matrix.

**2)** Find a unitary complex matrix $P$ such that $(MP)^H(MP)$ is a diagonal matrix.

I'm just starting in to a self-study of sorts with complex linear algebra and ran across this type of problem. I'm not even sure how to attack this and any advice would be great!

Comment: You can see an example for the real case for 1) [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587257/how-do-i-find-upper-triangular-form-of-a-given-3-by-3-matrix/587321#587321).